# How to use Embedding layer for RNN with a categorical feature - Classification Task for RecoSys

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, embedding

I would like to build a model (RNN >> LSTM) with an Embedding layer for a categorical feature (Item ID), My training set looks so:

**train_x  = [[[184563.1], [184324.1], [187853.1], [174963.1], [181663.1]], [[…],[…],[…],[…],[…]], …]**

I predict the sixth item ID:

**train_y = [0,1,2, …., 12691]**

I have 12692 unique item IDs, length of timesteps = 5 and this is a classification task.

This is a brief summary for what I've done so far: (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

1. One-hot-encoding for the categorical feature:

**train_x  = [[[1 0 0 … 0 0 0], [0 1 0 … 0 0 0], [0 0 1 … 0 0 0], […], […]], [[…],[…],[…],[…],[…]], …]**

2. Build model:

```py
model = Sequential()

model.add(Embedding(input_dim=12692 , output_dim=250, input_length=5))

model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)
model.add(Dropout(0.2)) 
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.1)) 
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(LSTM(128))
model.add(Dropout(0.2)) 
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(12692, activation='softmax'))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6)
model.compile(
      loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
      optimizer=opt,
      metrics=['accuracy'])

print(model.summary())

history = model.fit(
      train_x, train_y,
      batch_size=64,
      epochs=epochs,
      validation_data=(validation_x, validation_y))

score = model.evaluate(validation_x, validation_y, verbose=0)
```

I get this model summary:

[image]

Train on 131204 samples, validate on 107904 samples

But after that, this error appears:

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (131204, 5, 12692)

Where is my mistake and what would be the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The embedding layer turns positive integers (indexes) into dense vectors of fixed size [(Docs)](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/). So your `train_x` is not one-hot-encoded but the integer representing its index in the vocab. It will be the integer corresponding to the categorical feature.

`train_x.shape` will be `(No:of sample X 5)` --> Each representing the index of of the categorical feature

`train_y.shape` will be `(No:of sample)` --> Each representing the index of the sixth item in your time series.

#### Working sample

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.layers import Embedding, LSTM, Dense
n_samples = 100

train_x = np.random.randint(0,12692,size=(n_samples ,5))
train_y = np.random.randint(0,12692,size=(n_samples))


model = keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(Embedding(input_dim=12692+1, output_dim=250, input_length=5))
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(32))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(12692, activation='softmax'))

opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6)
model.compile(
      loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
      optimizer=opt,
      metrics=['accuracy'])

print(model.summary())

history = model.fit(
      train_x, train_y,
      batch_size=64,
      epochs=32)
```

Comment: THANK YOU for your answer. It would be great if you could explain these 3 points too: 1. why "+1" in input_dim=12692+1? 2. as you see in this example I'm taking only itemID as a feature into account if I want to include the price (numerical) as the second feature, how should I combine these two features as input in the model? 3. Do you have any suggestions to improve the model, like using: TimeDistributed or GRU?

Comment: 1. The first itemID is denoted as 1 not 0 so it will be `vocab_size + 1`( also mentioned in doc's link  I gave in the answer)
2. Create an input layer for other features and merge the output of the embedding layer with the input layer. 
3. You will have to experiment. Generally training with GRU is faster then LSTM but from the performance point (accuracy) both are almost same.